# Excel Dropdown Lists

Tags: excel, list, dropdown

I have a template and I have a column for type of consumable which I have a drop down list this is then used to complete the next column which is consumable.  The problem I have is that you can type anything in the consumable column and I don't want that to happen I need the cell to only be entered from a drop down list.

I would like to be able to stop people putting anything in the second column (consumables)

Comment: So you want the dropdown for the consumable column to be populated based on the value of the consumable type column? Can you show some sample data and an expected set of values?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to achieve.  I have managed to do this but I want it so the Consumable column you are not able to type in it, as at the moment you can type anything there and I need this to only have what ever is in the dropdown list only.

Comment: How do I attached a file

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen your data, I am making an assumption that you are looking for "Data Validation" feature in Excel. Simply go to Data -> Data Validation and select "List" from the dialog box that comes up. Then select the range where you have the list that you want the value to be selected from. The two screenshots below show how it could be done (assuming I need the list to be enabled for column K).

[image]

[image]